# Failed to load all correct information with Preload with gorm in golang

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have this gorm model in golang. Each students can have multiple sibling and each sibling are student as well.

```golang
type Student struct {
    UserID           uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt        time.Time
    UpdatedAt        time.Time
    DeletedAt        gorm.DeletedAt
    User             User           `gorm:"foreignKey:UserID"`
    Siblings         []Student      `gorm:"many2many:siblings;association_jointable_foreignkey:sibling_id"`

    LearningGroupID  uint
    LearningGroup    LearningGroup `gorm:"foreignKey:LearningGroupID"`
    DormitoryID      uint
    Dormitory        Dormitory `gorm:"foreignKey:DormitoryID"`
    StudentClubID    uint
    StudentClub      StudentClub `gorm:"foreignKey:StudentClubID"`
    AttendanceNumber uint
    Curriculum       string `gorm:"type:varchar(250);"`
}
type Sibling struct {
    StudentID uint `gorm:"primaryKey;column:student_id"`
    SiblingID uint `gorm:"primaryKey;column:sibling_id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt
}
```

I tried this code too:

```golang
type Sibling struct {
    StudentID uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Student   Student `gorm:"foreignKey:StudentID"`
    SiblingID uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Sibling   Student `gorm:"foreignKey:SiblingID"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt
}
```

And I'm listing all students like this:

```golang
func (r *repository) ListStudent(f *userDomain.StudentFilter) (students []*userDomain.Student,
    total int, err error,
) {
    var totalNumberInt64 int64

    query := r.dbConn.Model(userDomain.Student{}).
        Preload("User").
        Preload("StudentClub").
        Preload("LearningGroup").
        Preload("Dormitory").
        Preload("Siblings", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
            return db.Joins("JOIN siblings ON students.user_id = siblings.student_id OR students.user_id = siblings.sibling_id")
        }).
        Joins("JOIN users on users.id = students.user_id")

    ----------

    query = query.Count(&totalNumberInt64)

    if f.Base.Pagination {
        query = query.Limit(f.Base.PerPage).
            Offset(f.Base.PerPage * (f.Base.PageNum - 1))
    }

    if err := query.
        Find(&students).Error; err != nil {
        return nil, -1, err
    }
    return students, int(totalNumberInt64), nil
}
```

but I do not revive any of my siblings in the response. Each student has multiple sibling which are stored in the siblings table.